# how to visualize columns of a dataframe python as a plot?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
DateTime               ID          Temperature

2019-03-01 18:36:01    3             21

2019-04-01 18:36:01    3             21

2019-18-01 08:30:01    2             18

2019-12-01 18:36:01    2             12
```

I would like to visualize this as a plot, where I need the datetime in x-axis, and  Temperature on the y axis with a hue of IDs, I tried the below, but i need to see the Temperature distribution for every point more clearly. Is there any other visualization technique?

```
x= df['DateTime'].values
y= df['Temperature'].values
hue=df['ID'].values
plt.scatter(x, y,hue,color = "red")
```

Comment: for each ID a different color is good?

Comment: no, if there is a line of ID passing through this plot should be ideal.

Comment: @hakuna_code -  I think `plot bar` is ideal for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
df.set_index('DateTime').plot()
```

output:

[image]

or you can use:

```
df.set_index('DateTime').plot(style="x-", figsize=(15, 10))
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to plot voltage as a bar graph and mark label as points on them?

Comment: yes,  but this plot is fine ? or you want something different?

Comment: yes, but to understand the distribution better I would like to mark labels as points. Can you please show me how to do that?